# Unable to delete page in pdf using preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I received an encrypted pdf file. Usually, I'm able to delete and/or rearrange pages in the pdf using preview, but this one doesn't allow me that option. What is preventing me from making edits?

Comment: I'd presume it's because as soon as you change the content the cryptographic check is no longer valid .. unless it's a symettric cipher you can old decode the content, you don't know the key to re-encode it.

Comment: Basically the creator of the PDF password protected the PDF locking out certain specific things you can and can't do. Your only recourse is likely asking for the password, or an unlocked copy that permits deleting and rearranging pages.

Comment: @SteveChambers ah I see. If I take a screenshot (with the computer I opened the pdf on and with the internet connected) would they get notified? It’s a job offer letter that I’m trying to use to compete with other offers.

Comment: Nope, a screen capture, sends no usage data anywhere. Don't know if a locked PDF locks screen capture out like some DVDs (remember those!?) but it doesn't send info out

Answer (score 1):

If the document allows, you can print it out to a new pdf file. Then you edit this new one instead. I just did this with a document that only allowed this and text extraction.